# Implicit macros materialized based on type bound fail in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, macros

For the sake of backwards compatibility, I'm trying to get a simple macro working in Scala 2.10, however, in 2.10 the type bound is completely ignored.

```
implicit def createInstance[T <: Enumeration]: TypeClass[T#Value] = macro TypeClassMacro.enumMaterializer[T]
```

The `enumMaterializer` also re-enforces the type bound:

```
  def enumMaterializer[T <: Enumeration : c.WeakTypeTag](
    c: CrossVersionContext
  ): c.Expr[TypeClass[T#Value]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companion
    // .....
  }
```

This is a whitebox macro for what it's worth, and it compiles perfectly in Scala 2.11. In 2.10 however, the macro call is ambiguous. I have other instances of `TypeClass` defined in scope, that are defined by hand.

Macro expansion is used here to derive type classes for wrappers of `TypeClass`, such as `Option[TypeClass]` or `List[TypeClass]` or in the above case `Enumeration`.

But the compiler thinks the implicits are ambiguous because it's expecting `TypeClass[String]` to be `=:= TypeClass[Enum]`. Not sure how this happens exactly, given the type output by the macro is explicitly referring to `T#Value`, which is the inner type of the enum.

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both macro method enumTypeClass in object TypeClass of type [T <: Enumeration]=> com.bla.TypeClass[T#Value]
[error]  and object StringTypeClass in object TypeClass of type com.bla.TypeClass.StringTypeClass.type
```

I'm using Scala 2.10.6 and so far can only assume this is a bug.